# Move a cell's value and a formula reference to that cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets in a workbook where if there are multiples of a number in a list I need to move an adjacent column over 1. This adjacent column is being used in a formula in the sheet. I want the formula to reference the value in its new position.

This is the table before the code

[image: Table before code manipulation]

This is the ideal result where all the ones and fives had their numbers moved over 1 column but the formula still references the cell.

[image: Table after code manipulation]

I've written:

```
For i = 1 To WS_Count
    sheet_name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    row_count = Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

    For x = 11 To row_count
        cell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x, 1)
        If cell = "" Then GoTo NextIteration

        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x - 1, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x, 1) Or ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x + 1, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x, 1) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x, 4)
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(x, 4).ClearContents
        End If

NextIteration:
    Next x
Next i
```

The cut is not working properly over the multiple sheets. It doesn't properly move to the new sheet.

Is there a way to move a cell's value and the reference to the cell from the formula over multiple sheets?

Comment: You appear to be assigning values from one cell to another. Doing so will overwrite any formula (in the destination cell) with just a static value. Instead you might want to use `Range.Cut`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Cut the values over:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, x As Long, row_count As Long, v

For i = 1 To WS_Count

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    row_count = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

    For x = 11 To row_count
        v = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            If ws.Cells(x - 1, 1) = v Or ws.Cells(x + 1, 1) = v Then
                ws.Cells(x, 4).Cut ws.Cells(x, 5)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you. I attempted this before i submitted the questions but the way i set the active workbook was messing me up too. This worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy the formula?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula

The algorithm

```
for.... 
   if ....  
      You can copy formula to the adjacent cell, then empty the cell
```

If you copy directly the formula from one cell to the another, the formula doesn't change